# Why Jquery Input Function doesnt return complete url?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make preview to my uploading Images. I have wrote a function its works fine but it doesnt return the complete url of file which is selected locally.

```
function imagePreview(pid, input){

$("#"+pid).attr("src", input.value);
$("#"+pid).fadeIn('slow');
}
```

Html is

```
<input type="file" class="round sinput" onchange="imagePreview('img1', this);" name="f_pic" id="f_pic" />
```

this function loads image.jpg not c:\website\image.jpg (complete path which is required to display image)

thank you

Comment: It can be a security feature of the browser. Have you tried any other browser?

Comment: possible duplicate of [is it possible to preview local images before uploading them via a form?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/922057/is-it-possible-to-preview-local-images-before-uploading-them-via-a-form)

Comment: It doesn't return a URL because it contains a file (and some meta data about the file), not a URL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't know absolute path to local file selected by user. It's forbidden for security reasons.