# How to re-size an image and preview it before uploading

Tags: javascript, file-upload, image-resizing, preview, aspect-ratio

I have an input->type->file button which allow users to upload images.
I am trying to preview the image before they can submit(upload) it. Can anyone help me solve, how can I re-size the image (before clicking submit) to fit the div (for the preview).

**css**

```
#preview_box{
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-left:10px;
    float:left;
    display:inline;
    text-align:center;
    height:408px;
    width:490px;
    position:relative;
    border: 1px solid #adadad; /* stroke */
    background-color: #fff; /* layer fill content */
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.22); /* drop shadow */
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.22); /* drop shadow */
    box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.22); /* drop shadow */
}
```

**html**

```
<div id="preview_box">This is a preview</div>

<form id="imageform" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="/help/upload.php">                     
      <input name="photoimg" id="photoimg" type="file"/>
</form>
```

**jquery**

```
$("input[name='photoimg']").on("change", function(){
  var files = !!this.files ? this.files : [];
  // If no files were selected, or no FileReader support, return
  if ( !files.length || !window.FileReader ) return;
  // Only proceed if the selected file is an image
 if ( /^image/.test( files[0].type ) ) { 
  // Create a new instance of the FileReader
    reader = new FileReader();
   // Read the local file as a DataURL
    reader.readAsDataURL( files[0] );
   // When loaded, set image data as background of page
     reader.onloadend = function(){
    $("#preview_box").css("background-image", "url(" + this.result + ")");
      }
   }
});
```

Thanks. 
(it will be great if I can keep the aspect-ratio when re-sizing the image)

Answer (score 0):

> ... preview it before uploading

Can be done in latest versions of most browsers. See:

[is it possible to preview local images before uploading them via a form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922057/is-it-possible-to-preview-local-images-before-uploading-them-via-a-form?rq=1)

However, for backward compatibility, I suggest you upload the images via ajax and perform the image resize + crop in a separate dialog.