# Get SRC of image previewed in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, image-upload

### WHAT I'M DOING

I'm trying to implement profile picture changing in php/jquery. When an image is uploaded the preview of the image is shown.

### WHAT I REQUIRE

I want to get the src of the previewed image. When i use `$('img').attr('src');` it gives the src of the old image and not the new previewed image.

### SCRIPT

```
function readURL(input) {
     if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function (e) {
      var image =  $('#img').attr('src', e.target.result);
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
     }
     }
    $("#imgInp").change(function(){
      readURL(this);
     });
```

### HTML

```
 <div class="pic">

  <form id="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data">

   <img src="profile.jpg" width="150"  alt="profile" title="" id="img"/>

     <span>Change Picture?</span>

      <div class="up">

         <input type='file' name ="file" id="imgInp"  />

     </div>

         <input type="submit" name="picture" id="picture" value="Update"/>

    </form>

 </div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [is it possible to preview local images before uploading them via a form?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/922057/is-it-possible-to-preview-local-images-before-uploading-them-via-a-form)

Comment: @DerekHenderson: Actually i have already implemented image preview. I want the src of the previewed image

Comment: Wouldn't that be the value of your file input?

Comment: @DerekHenderson: but when i alert file input i m getting something like fakepath/image.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a new security "feature" in IE 8 that hides the real path of the selected file from JavaScript calls (it returns c:\fakepath). This seems to only be activated for "Internet" servers ... not Local intranet servers...

[See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851595/how-to-resolve-the-c-fakepath) for more information about C:\fakepath

**Edit**

Also, you should consider removing this line of code (you don't need it in your script)...

```
reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
```